# Automatic change of hotspot network name on Android Phone

Tags: wifi, mobile, android, hotspot

I saw this sudden change in my hotspot name.
It has been months since I last used it. Is this something to be concerned about?
My colleague also saw something similar where both his network name and password were changed to something weird.

[image: Screenshot with the change in name]

Comment: Have you upgraded your phone or make any big changes to it in those few months?

Comment: I had one system security update plus regular app updates but my colleague's settings were alright till yesterday and he has not done any upgrade since then. It was only when he reported this when I noticed changes in my device.

Comment: You might be using Share it and Xender for data transfer. While using these apps they create their own hotspot with new randomly assigned SSID and open security. The same SSID is similar to mine when I use those apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539481/how-do-i-change-the-portable-hotspots-ssid-in-android-programmatically) post. The name can change if the internal app changes. So an upgrade of the apk or even if you upgrade the system can do this change.

You say in your comment that your colleague didn't made a system upgrade. Ok, maybe only upgrade his apps on play store. That's enough.